# Firebase not exchanging AccessToken for Firebase credential?

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I am very new to Firebase but I am creating an app which uses the Facebook Login feature to allow users to log in. My code can retrieve the AccessToken provided when a users logs in however it is not be exchanged for a Firebase credential when I call `handleFacebookAccessToken()`

My app does not crash so there is no stack trace.

```
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d("FB Token", "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("Sign-in Successful", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("Sign-in failed", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

This is where I call the method

```
      mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                final Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                handleFacebookAccessToken(accessToken);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have trace. Could you see what is the value of "FB Token" and "Sign-in failed"? If you can't see anything, write these values on the log search input. If no luck, execute the app again on debug mode using breakpoints (You could add them at the beggining of your method handleFacebookAccessToken). This will give you the opportunity to see the values on live